# Any open source database options like MYSql which can work from ASp.net App folder

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, open-source

I am searching for a open source database option which may work from the ASP .net app folder. (I know its some sort of stand alone) .

Here I am trying to avoid the installation of a database server by utilizing the app folder option at least in the development machines.

I could only find two as of now, one is the access and the second is sql server from visual studio.

Any suggestions in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are

- SQLite
- Firebird
- H2 Database
- Berkeley DB

Other open source engines that require a db server

- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- MongoDB
- HSQLDB

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That saved some time of mine.